# JQuery POST to wordpress PHP plugin execution

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a script on my Wordpress page, implemented via a code block from the visual page builder.  What I want to know is, how do I pass the correct URL to reach my PHP file?  Since it's in the block of the page builder, I don't think I can use ajax_admin as the url since the file is never enqueued.

```
$("#submit_button").click(function(e,features,totalcost){
  e.preventDefault();
   console.log('clicked')
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: '/wp-content/plugins/estimate/estimate.php',
      data: {
      action: 'submitWizard',
// add your parameters here
      features: features,
      total:totalcost,
      email:$("#exampleInputEmail1").value,
      name:$("#exampleInputPassword1").value,
      message:$("#exampleFormControlTextarea1").value,
      },
      success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
      }
      });
})
```

And I have a plugin called estimate with this code:

```
 add_action( 'wp_ajax_submitWizard', 'process_estimate' );

function process_estimate(){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $features = $_POST['features'];
    $total = $_POST['total'];

    wp_mail( 'charlespettisappdevelopment@gmail.com', 'New Submission!', "
        $name,
        $email,
        $message,
        $features,
        $total,
  ");
}
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: @ezra , sorry that could've been useful.  I'm getting 500 server errors when trying to call this function.  I guess my question is, how do I pass the correct URL in the jquery post settings.

Comment: a 500 post error means an error on the server-side. That means there's an issue with your php code. Also, go onto chrome developer tools and see if the post parameters are being sent correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `estimate.php` add this code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wi_enqueue_scripts' ); 
function wi_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_localize_script( 'wi-ajax-script', 'wi_ajax_params', 
        array(
            'wi_ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wi_ajax_nonce' ),
            'wi_ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
        )
    );
}
```

Then in javascript file use this:

```
$("#submit_button").click(function(e, features, totalcost) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('clicked')
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //url: wi_ajax_params.wi_ajax_url,
        url: "http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'submitWizard',
            // add your parameters here
            features: features,
            total: totalcost,
            email: $("#exampleInputEmail1").value,
            name: $("#exampleInputPassword1").value,
            message: $("#exampleFormControlTextarea1").value,
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Last, add this code again to plugin file:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_submitWizard', 'process_estimate' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_submitWizard', 'process_estimate' );
function process_estimate(){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $features = $_POST['features'];
    $total = $_POST['total'];

    wp_mail( 'charlespettisappdevelopment@gmail.com', 'New Submission!', "
        $name,
        $email,
        $message,
        $features,
        $total,
  ");
}
```

Not tested but it should work. Let me know.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your time, I thought whis would work but I'm getting "wi_ajax_params is not defined".  Do you think this could be because I'm calling my JS function inside <script> tags on the wordpress visual builder?

Comment: Maybe. You could create a js file and enqueue with `wi-ajax-script` this handler. Then paste the js code there.

Comment: @CharlesPettis Or you can change the this `url: "http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",`. http://yourdomain.com should be replaced with your domain name

Comment: Perfect! Thank you~